# Sql to Dql using Where Not In or Not Exists

Tags: sql, dql, not-exists, notin

I'm trying to find a list of invoices where the invoice id does not appear in another table with certain parameters. This problem has been bugging me all day. I've tried variations of not exist and not in.

Here's the sql I'm ultimately trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices 
JOIN invoiceitem 
WHERE invoiceitem.class = 'ITEM' 
AND invoices.rmlist >= $date1 
AND invoices.rmlist <= $date2 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM invoice_history 
WHERE invoices.id = invoice_history.invid 
AND invoice_history.ttype = 'PR' 
AND invoice_history.note = 'Vouchers Printed') 
AND invoiceitem.voucherrequired = 1 
GROUP BY invoices.id 
ORDER BY invoices.depdate ASC
```

From what I've learned trying to figure this out, there is no "Not Exists" in dql(don't quote me on that), so I've been trying to use the "Not In" method instead. Essentially, this is where all my efforts have brought me:

```
$q2 = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->from('ClicctTravelBundle:InvoiceHistory', 'ih')
                    ->Where("ih.ttype = 'PR'")
                    ->andWhere("ih.note = 'Vouchers Printed'")
                    ->groupBy('ih.invid');

                $qb->leftJoin('i.history', 'h')
                    ->where($qb->expr()->notExist('i.id', $q2->select('ih.invid')->getDQL()));
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

[edit]
I believe I've solved my issue. This code seems to be working for me:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('ClicctTravelBundle:Invoices', 'i')
        ->join('i.invoiceitems', 'b')          
        ->select('i')
        ->Where("b.class = 'ITEM'")
        ->andWhere("i.rmlist >=:fdate")
        ->setParameter("fdate",$fromdate)
        ->andWhere("i.rmlist <=:tdate")
        ->setParameter("tdate",$todate)
        ->orderBy('i.depdate')
        ->groupBy('b.invoiceno');

$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("h")
                ->from("ClicctTravelBundle:InvoiceHistory","h")
                ->andWhere("h.invid = i.id")
                ->andWhere("h.note = 'Vouchers Printed'");

            $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->not($qb->expr()->exists($qb2->getDQL())));
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I don't know DQL, so I'm not sure how you'd do it, but I've always found `NOT IN`s to be _very_inefficient. If you can rework your query, a much more performant way is to do `SELECT a.id FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS NULL`. This is functionally the same as the `NOT IN`, but allows the optimizer to make a much better query plan.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems to be working, but I'm having trouble adding my other parameters. I keep getting syntax errors no matter what I try.

    SELECT * FROM invoices
    JOIN invoiceitem WHERE invoiceitem.class = 'ITEM'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_history ON invoices.id =    invoice_history.invid WHERE invoice_history.invid IS NULL

Gives me a syntax error.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: I'm not sure if DQL can do a JOIN like that. Though I don't understand why it couldn't. I'm not a huge fan of ORMs for reasons like this. This should be a relatively simple query, but an ORM makes it a good bit more complex. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Your join does not have a join condition, I have added one. You can get the same effect as NOT EXISTS by comparing 0 to the count. In addition, all your columns that are not part of the GROUP BY must have aggregate functions applied to them.

```
  SELECT invoices.id, max(invoices.depdate) as depdate
    FROM invoices JOIN invoiceitem ON (invoices.id= invoiceitem.id)
   WHERE invoiceitem.class = 'ITEM'
     AND invoices.rmlist >= $date1
     AND invoices.rmlist <= $date2
     AND 0 = 
             (SELECT count(*) c
                FROM invoice_history
               WHERE invoices.id = invoice_history.invid
                 AND invoice_history.ttype = 'PR'
                 AND invoice_history.note = 'Vouchers Printed')
     AND invoiceitem.voucherrequired = 1
GROUP BY invoices.id
ORDER BY depdate ASC
```

Comment: Hmm. This sql query seems to return 0 results for me. Really appreciate your help though. The sql in my question actually gave me the correct results I was looking for. I just need to turn it into dql.